# C# discover TCP client dissapeared

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a TCPServer running like this :

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        client = tcpClient;

        bool Stop = false;
        byte[] response = new byte[1024];
        while (!ServerController.Token.IsCancellationRequested && !Stop)
        {
            Array.Clear(response, 0, response.Length);
            var amount = tcpClient.Client.Receive(response);
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            if (amount == 0)
            {
                Stop = true;
                ServerController.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            else
                ProcesNewMessage(data);
        }
        if (ServerController.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
            ServerController.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        tcpClient.Close();

        Debug(exc.Message);
        ServerController.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

}, ServerController.Token).ContinueWith(
    (result) =>
    {
        clientDisconnected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    });
}
```

First of all the cancellation token does not work. I guess this is for another question.

My problem is detecting exiting sockets. In the case of a nice close by the socket at the other side I receive zero bytes (cached in the `amount` variable) but, the really troublesome scenario is unexpected disconnections from the client (power down, close the terminal, etc etc)  How do I detect them ?

My clients are Arduino like chips so they are prone to die unexpectedly. How do I notice it?

PS: I'd like to avoid heartbeats since my devices run on batteries and sending over WiFi is my main lose of energy

Comment: You need to pay attention to the return value from `Receive`. It tells you *how many bytes* have just been populated in your buffer. And there's no guarantee that, whatever that number is, it corresponds to a single call to `Send` at the other end. TCP is a *stream of bytes*, not *messaging* (and it being 0 is how you detect graceful shutdown)

Comment: I tested with a python client on windows and closing the terminal does not send any empty message. Will a dying arduino send this empty message when unexpectedly powered down ? (I have none here with me to test)

Comment: No, I wasn't addressing the unexpected shutdown scenario. I was discussing a) you always converting the complete buffer to a string using a multibyte encoding where you've no guarantee that the buffer contains complete characters and b) trying to detect graceful shutdown by seeing if nothing has overwritten the start of the buffer.

Comment: Nice.  I see if it returns zero I know they disconnected (gracefully). How do I know there are stills bytes to read? because the returned int and the Count of the bytes do not match ??

Comment: Like I said, it's just a stream of bytes. If you want *messaging*, it's up to you to implement that atop TCP (or move to a higher level protocol that does messaging). Common strategies are fixed size messages (loop until you've filled your buffer), fixed message types (read enough to determine message type, then size buffer appropriate and read in loop) or length-prefixing messages (read 4 bytes in a loop, that tells you how big a buffer to use, now loop to fill that)

Comment: If I go for prefixed array length then when sending I've to check how many bytes I'm sending, and fill it with predefined characters till the prefixed length. Then when reading in I keep on reading till I have my buffer filled. Is this how it works ?